# Why IIS is still blocking Web.config even after setting denyUrlSequences and fileExtensions?

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404, request-filtering

One of the IIS sites I manage forwards all the requests to Apache. This means that any request, including requests to files such as `.config`, should be forwarded.

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <denyUrlSequences>
            <clear />
        </denyUrlSequences>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
            <clear />
            <add fileExtension=".config" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

doesn't help, since IIS is still blocking `.config` files. What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The missing part is:

```
<hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="false">
    <clear />
</hiddenSegments>
```

After adding this block to `security/requestFiltering`, files with `.config` extension can be served by IIS.